# "diff --starting-file=FILE"how to use this option?

Tags: diff

I'm reading about source code of 'diff' recently,and I'm confuzing about diff -S[FILE] or --starting-file=FILE option.I have done some tests to verify it,but I can't get what I want.there are something about my tests:

```
ls -l /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/

-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat    9  5月  9 13:46 diff.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat    9  5月  9 13:57 file_a
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat    9  5月  9 13:57 file_b
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat    9  5月  9 13:57 file_c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat   20  5月  9 11:46 heh.c

ls -l /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/

-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat 5  5月  9 11:45 diff.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat 5  5月  9 13:56 testfile_a
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat 5  5月  9 13:56 testfile_b
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat 5  5月  9 13:56 testfile_c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Nibnat Nibnat 5  5月  9 13:56 testfile_d
```

/tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/diff.c is different from /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/diff.c,when I want to compare these two directories,I want compare from /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/file_a(skip diff.c),so I use command

```
'diff -S /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/file_a /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/ /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/'
```

I get this:

```
diff -S /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/file_a /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/diff.c /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/diff.c
1c1
< hahahehe
---
> haha
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: file_a
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: file_b
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: file_c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: heh.c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: test_a.c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: test_b.c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/diffutils-2.7/: test_c.c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/: testfile_a
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/: testfile_b
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/: testfile_c
Only in /tmp/Nibnat/test_dir/: testfile_d
```

it still did't skip diff.c.
any help is thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-S diff.c`, i.e. just the filename, not the complete pathname:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/TST/a
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 3 Apr 25 16:16 diff.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 2 Apr 25 16:17 file_a
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 2 Apr 25 16:17 file_b
$ ls -l /tmp/TST/b
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 3 Apr 25 16:16 diff.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 2 Apr 25 16:17 testfile_a
-rw-r--r-- 1 orpe orpe 2 Apr 25 16:17 testfile_b
$ diff /tmp/TST/a /tmp/TST/b
diff /tmp/TST/a/diff.c /tmp/TST/b/diff.c
1c1
< aa
---
> bb
Only in /tmp/TST/a: file_a
Only in /tmp/TST/a: file_b
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_a
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_b
$ diff -S file_a /tmp/TST/a /tmp/TST/b
Only in /tmp/TST/a: file_a
Only in /tmp/TST/a: file_b
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_a
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_b
$ diff -S file_b /tmp/TST/a /tmp/TST/b
Only in /tmp/TST/a: file_b
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_a
Only in /tmp/TST/b: testfile_b
$
```